# How can one copy the internal state of zlib compressor object in Python

Tags: python, compression, zlib

I have to compress a long list of strings. I have to compress them individually. Each string is less than 1000 chars long. However many of these strings have a common prefix. Therefore I was wondering if I could amortize the compression cost, by compressing the common prefix first and then storing the state of the compressor and feed it the suffix of the strings.

If you have any suggestions about how to accomplish this in Python that would be great. Although I mention zlib in the title any other standard module will work too. In this application speed of decompression does not matter much, so I can afford decompression to be quite slow.

Comment: How many strings are in this list? Consider using a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie ?

Comment: @cldy Oh that is not in my control. I have to compress these strings and then send several different subsets as demanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python interface to zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) is rather meager, and does not provide access to all of [zlib's capabilities](http://zlib.net/manual.html).  If you can construct your own interface to zlib, then you can do what you're asking, and more.

The "and more" has to do with the fact that you are compressing very short strings individually, which inherently limits how much compression you can get.  Since these strings have some common content, you should use the `deflateSetDictionary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()` functions of zlib to take advantage of that fact, and potentially improve the compression significantly.  The common content can be the common prefix you mention, as well as common content anywhere else in the string.  You would define a fixed dictionary to use for all strings of up to 32K that contains sequences of bytes that appear commonly in the strings.  You would put the most common sequences at the end of the 32K, and less common sequences earlier.  If there are several classes of these strings with different common sequences, you can if you like create a set of dictionaries and use the dictionary id returned from the first call of `inflate()` to select the dictionary.  For one or several dictionaries, you just need to make sure that the same dictionaries are stored on both the compression and decompression ends.

As for storing the compression state, you can do that with `deflateCopy()`.  This is provided in Python with the `copy()` method.  I'm not sure that that will give you much of a speed advantage though for small strings.

**Update:**

From recently added comments, I believe that your use case is that you send some of many strings on request to a receiver.  There may be a way to get much better compression using the meager Python interface in this case.  You can use the `flush` method with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` to force what has been compressed so far to the output.  What this would allow you to do is treat the series of strings requested as a single compressed stream.

The process would be that you start a compression object with `compressobj()`, use `compress()` on that object with the first string requested, collect the output of that (if any), and then do a `flush(Z_SYNC_FLUSH)` on the object, collecting the remaining output.  Send the combined output of `compress()` and `flush()` to the receiver, which has started a `decompressobj()` and it then uses `decompress()` on that object with what it was sent, which will return the original string.  (No flush is needed on the decompression end.)

So far, the result is not much different than just compressing that first string.  The good part is that you repeat that process without creating new compress or decompress objects.  Just use `compress()` and `flush()` for the next string, and `decompress()` on the other end to get it.  The advantage for the second string, and all subsequent strings, is that they get to use the history of the previous strings for compression.  Then you do not need to construct or use any fixed dictionaries.  You can just use the history of previously requested strings to provide the fodder needed for good compression.  If your strings average 1000 bytes in length, eventually each string sent will benefit from the history of the most recently sent 32 strings, since the sliding window for compression is 32K long.

When you're done, just close the objects.

Comment: Yeah I had familiarized myself with `deflateSetDictionary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()` so was looking for something in Python's standard library that exposes the compression dictionary. Upvoting because this will be helpful for others. I have to send the prefix, because I only have to send a smallish subset of the strings and they need not have a common prefix. This is for offline processing to create a lookup table. Yes the Python's zlib is really impoverished, wonder why.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Unfortunately I cannot afford to compress at runtime, and I have considered using flush(Z_SYNC_FLUSH) after I have fed the common prefix. Wish I could maintain that state, because once I feed in the suffix that state is gone. Reading between the lines, I think you are saying that even if that state is gone, there is a high chance that it "remembers" the prefix. What I need is that the subsequent strings with the common prefix are compressed faster. I care about compression speed, not about decompression.

Comment: I do need that each string can be independently decompressed.

Comment: You _can_ maintain the state in order to speed up compression.  See the mention of the `copy()` method in Python's zlib interface.  Depending on the length of the prefix this may or may not be a win.  A lot of data has to be copied in the copy operation.

Comment: Please describe your application in the question.  That would make it much easier to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: Ah! copy does it. It must be new, I never knew it was there. Could you update your answer with this, then I can accept it.

Comment: It turns out that copy is extremely expensive ! 1.1 milisecond per call

Comment: As I said, I am doubtful it would be a win for short prefixes.  The copy operation copies about half a megabyte of data.

Comment: since python3.3 compressobj and decompressobj have a zdict argument which behind the scene call deflateSetDictionary() and inflateSetDictionary()