# Missing .copy() on zlib decompressobj in Python

Tags: python, zlib

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) of the `zlib` module, `decompressobj` objects have a `copy()` function to clone the decompressor's state.  This equivalent functionality is also mentioned for the compressing side on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662745/how-can-one-copy-the-internal-state-of-zlib-compressor-object-in-python).

However, when I try to use it, it simply doesn't exist:

```
C:\>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zlib
>>> meow = zlib.decompressobj()
>>> purr = meow.copy()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: copy
```

Is this a bug in Python?  I tried searching for this subject, but too many false hits get in the way.

Comment: Works as described in the doc with Python 2.7.8 and 3.3.0 on Linux. Could someone confirm that behavior on Windows ?

Comment: Works fine on both linux and windows 2.7.9 (doesn't throw attrib error) so whatever is the cause for it - it is most likely with something in your box.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  It's a [known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue13194) that was fixed in newer versions of 2.7.  I just needed to check the bug list.  For some reason, Google didn't index that bug page.